# Angular 4 images not working while in production on Ubuntu

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core2.0 Angular 4 web application. Everything works fine while on my win10 development machine both in production and development mode.

However, when I move my project onto my Ubtuntu server, the website works well. The only problem is that my images do not load. Here is the error I get in google chrome console.

```
GET http://website.com/dist/43372b1b70866a10fca54433dba94a53.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://website.com/dist/main-client.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Example of using image path:
`<img src="../../../src/assets/images/post1.jpg"/>`

I'm thinking this is because of the environment change going from Windows to Ubuntu. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Here is the output after running on my ubuntu machine:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /sites/jeninja/blog
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

*One thing I should mention: I removed ClientApp/dist from my .gitignore (if that changes anything)

Comment: I don't know much about Deployment in a production server but what I do know is that you have to make all the requests go through index.html using a config file. Have you created any such file and if yes, then have you provided URL rewrite for static contents such as images and videos?

Comment: @ArjunPanicker I don't know what config file to use if that is the case.

Comment: Okay.. what server are you using as production server?

Comment: @ArjunPanicker Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm running NGINX to broadcast my app.

Comment: Be sure to name files in lower-case since window file names are case-insensitive, but linux filenames are case sensitive

Comment: Can you share the `conf` file of nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by running: `dotnet publish` in the root directory of my project.

This creates a /publish folder within Debug/.

Inside this directory, issue `dotnet <projectname>.dll` to properly run the .NET Core application.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server